# Need help editing a Message Queue System

Tags: c#

I'm new to coding and I'm editing an open source IRC bot written in C#. The server puts a limit of 20 messages every 30 seconds. I believe the bot already uses a C# messageQueue, but I don't understand how it works. I was wondering if someone can please help me edit it to fit the server limit. The bot uses sendMessage to send the string message with an int priority. Thanks for your time in advance.

```
 private Timer messageQueue;

 messageQueue = new Timer(handleMessageQueue, null, 0, 4000);    

 private void handleMessageQueue(Object state)
    {
        String message;
        //Console.WriteLine("Entering Message Queue.  Time: " + DateTime.Now);
        if (highPriority.TryDequeue(out message))
        {
            print(nick + ": " + message);
            sendRaw("PRIVMSG " + channel + " :" + message);
            messageQueue.Change(4000, Timeout.Infinite);
        }
        else if (normalPriority.TryDequeue(out message))
        {
            print(nick + ": " + message);
            sendRaw("PRIVMSG " + channel + " :" + message);
            messageQueue.Change(4000, Timeout.Infinite);
        }
        else if (lowPriority.TryDequeue(out message))
        {
            print(nick + ": " + message);
            sendRaw("PRIVMSG " + channel + " :" + message);
            messageQueue.Change(4000, Timeout.Infinite);
        }
        else messageQueue.Change(4000, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    private void sendMessage(String message, int priority)
    {
        if (priority == 1)
        {
            highPriority.Enqueue(message);
        }
        else if (priority == 2)
        {
            normalPriority.Enqueue(message);
        }
        else lowPriority.Enqueue(message);
    }
```

Edited: I was told there is no messageQueue system in the code. Here is the source: http://sourceforge.net/p/twitchmodbot/source/ci/master/tree/ModBot/ The code above is found in Irc.cs.

Comment: You should mention and link to the open source project that you are modifying. A quick glance at the code block you have here, it does not contain any quota or limitation of the number of messages to be processed from the queue. maybe the limitation is in the queue implementation itself or somewhere else.

Comment: This is the whole message source, so I guess it just doesn't have a queue system. I saw messageQueue in the code, so I assumed it. I will edit the post with a link to it.

Comment: There are queues in your code: `highPriority`, `normalPriority`, `lowPriority`. But you haven't asked a question.

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet, the processing of the queue is done using a timer.

```
private Timer messageQueue;
messageQueue = new Timer(handleMessageQueue, null, 0, 4000);
```

this means that the handleMessageQueue method will be called once every 4000 milliseconds (4 seconds) to process the queue of messages.

Here is the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yb9at7c(v=vs.110).aspx) for the used Timer constructors.

I will quote it here:

```
public Timer(
    TimerCallback callback,
    Object state,
    long dueTime,
    long period
)
```

The parameters are explained as:

> **callback**: A TimerCallback delegate representing a method to be executed.
>
> **state**: An object containing information to be used by the callback method, or null.
>
> **dueTime**: The amount of time to delay before callback is invoked, in milliseconds. Specify Timeout.Infinite to prevent the timer from starting. Specify zero (0) to start the timer immediately.
>
> **period**: The time interval between invocations of callback, in milliseconds. Specify Timeout.Infinite to disable periodic signaling.

Simply changing the timer interval to something of lower value will means more frequent processing of the queue, which will increase the throughput.